# Heroku CLI: User [user] is a team admin and cannot be joined on app [app]

Tags: bash, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to simply execute `heroku run [app-name]` for a Heroku app that is within a Heroku Team I created so that I can import my .SQL file to the app's add-on MariaDB.

When I try to use `heroku apps:join -a [app-name]`, I get an error `User [my-user] is a team admin and cannot be joined on app [app-name]`.

When I use `heroku run [app-name]`, I get an error `Couldn't find that app.`

Yes, I'm logged in to Heroku. I've been trying at this for probably 6 hours now and have had no luck. Any help on how I can run my bash command would be so appreciated.

Hope you are all staying safe,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `heroku access` to see what account already had access to this app.
I think you are trying to add an account which having access (Team Admin) already.

Thanks.